# In which Tables Magento store product information when we import products using csv

Tags: magento, import, product

I am importing a products csv from Magento admin. I want to know which tables are effected by the product import.

Comment: Which version of Magento? Magento stores things in EAV format meaning that one _logical_ table is dispersed over many _physical_ tables. Take a look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1 to understand Magento's EAV system.

Comment: @Max Yours is the best short description of the process I've found yet. Each product is an entity assigned an ID which then serves as the key to all it's attribute keys. Each attribute's value is assigned to a table by datatype. You find them by matching lots of keys... Alan Storm helped me understand EAV also. Accessing Magento collections is the way to go to retrieve stuff from this, the SQL required will drive you crazy.

Comment: it seems to me you will import by SQL, this is not good way. you might face of many troubles with this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually magento using EAV model.so there are many tables which is using for store product information.
In controller file you will get expoprtCSV() method which is responsible for generate csv file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great breakdown of affected tables on new product creation here:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101152/what-are-the-main-tables-that-updated-when-we-creating-new-product-in-magento